# Dynamic menu with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, ng-view

I got a web application with two menus, one on the top position the other on the left. Both menus' options will be retrieved from a DB according to the logged profile. However, the menu isn't rendering when there's a change in the route.

**Shell.js:**

```
<section>
 <div data-ng-include="'app/controllers/layout/header.html'"></div>
 <div id="menuDin" data-ng-include="'app/autenticado/menuDinamico.html'"></div>
 <div id="corpo" ng-view=""></div>
 <div data-ng-include="'app/controllers/layout/footer.html'"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: What does console returns?

Comment: It returns the menu items correctly, but isn't showing up on the screen.

Comment: If you call a `$scope.$digest()` manually in the console, does the view update?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an object with items from their menu for your controller and then use `ng-repeat` to draw the menu.

```
class MyController
constructor: ->
    @itens_menu = [ 
        {label: 'MenuA', href: 'urlA'}, 
        {label: 'MenuB', href: 'urlB'}
    ]

<ul ng-controller="MyCtrl as MyController">
        <li ng-repeat="item in MyCtrl.itens_menu">
            <a href="{{item.href}}">{{item.label}}</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```